# Jenkins CI npm install fails ENOENT node_modules/dependency/node_modules/child-dependency/package.json.xxxx

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, groovy, lerna

When trying to install a scoped module in a lerna project on a Jenkins pipeline with the below Groovy code:

```
stage("Install") {
      sh "npm ci && ./node_modules/.bin/lerna bootstrap"
    }
    dir("www") {
      stage('Build') {
        sh "npm i"
```

```sh
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/branch/ac6d3a63-0c50-45ad-8329-3b166b4d224d/www
/node_modules/@scope/module-name/node_modules/@scope/child-module
/node_modules/node-fetch/package.json.3128746531'
```

The suffix `.3128746531` is somehow being randomly appended to a child dependencies package.json file name, which of course doesn't exist.

If I don't install within the `dir`, then when I go to push the folder to a remote server, the `lerna boostrap` doesn't seem to have added all of the dependencies, and the local dependencies are missing (I am doing `file:./path/to/module` in the package.json).

Any ideas on what is adding the suffix to the path?